# Matlab, Econometrics toolbox - Simulate ARIMA with deterministic time-varying variance

Tags: time-series, matlab, simulate

**DISCLAIMER:** This question is only for those who have access to the econometrics toolbox in Matlab.

**The Situation:** I would like to use Matlab to simulate `N` observations from an ARIMA(p, d, q) model using the econometrics toolbox. What's the difficulty? I would like the innovations to be simulated with deterministic, time-varying variance.

**Question 1)** Can I do this using the in-built matlab `simulate` function *without altering it myself*? As near as I can tell, this is not possible. From my reading of the docs, the innovations can either be specified to have a constant variance (ie same variance for each innovation), or be specified to be stochastically time-varying (eg a GARCH model), but they cannot be deterministically time-varying, where I, the user, choose their values (except in the trivial constant case).

**Question 2)** If the answer to **question 1** is "No", then does anyone see any reason why I can't edit the `simulate` function from the econometrics toolbox as follows:
a) Alter the preamble such that the function won't throw an error if the `Variance` field in the input `model` is set to a numeric vector instead of a numeric scalar.
b) Alter line 310 of `simulate` from:

```
E(:,(maxPQ + 1:end)) = Z * sqrt(variance);
```

to

```
E(:,(maxPQ + 1:end)) = (ones(NumPath, 1) * sqrt(variance)) .* Z;
```

where `NumPath` is the number of paths to be simulated, and it can be assumed that I've included an error trap to ensure that the (input) deterministic variance path stored in `variance` is of the right length (ie equal to the number of observations to be simulated per path).

Any help would be most appreciated. Apologies if the question seems basic, I just haven't ever edited one of Mathwork's own functions before and didn't want to do something foolish.

**UPDATE (2012-10-18):** I'm confident that the code edit I've suggested above is valid, and I'm mostly confident that it won't break anything else. However it turns out that implementing the solution is not trivial due to file permissions. I'm currently talking with Mathworks about the best way to achieve my goal. I'll post the results here once I have them.

Comment: As usual, a question that can not be answered in 5 seconds ;)

Comment: @angainor But those are usually the good ones :-) I realize q2 is a tough one to answer - I'm hoping there are some other time series guys/gals out there who've run into this problem. If not, I'll do some tests tomorrow and post the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a week and a half with no answer, so I think I'm probably okay to post my own answer at this point.

In response to my **question 1)**, no, I have not found anyway to do this with the built-in matlab functions.

In response to my **question 2)**, yes, what I have posted will work. However, it was a little more involved than I imagined due to matlab file permissions. Here is a step-by-step guide:

**i)** Somewhere in your matlab path, create the directory `@arima_Custom`.

**ii)** In the command window, type `edit arima`. Copy the text of this file into a new m file and save it in the directory `@arima_Custom` with the filename `arima_Custom.m`.

**iii)** Locate the econometrics toolbox on your machine. Once found, look for the directory `@arima` in the toolbox. This directory will probably be located (on a Linux machine) at something like `$MATLAB_ROOT/toolbox/econ/econ/@arima` (on my machine, $MATLAB_ROOT is at /usr/local/Matlab/R2012b). Copy the contents of `@arima` to `@arima_Custom`, except do NOT copy the file `arima.m`.

**iv)** Open `arima_Custom` for editing, ie `edit arima_Custom`. In this file change line 1 from:

```
classdef (Sealed) arima < internal.econ.LagIndexableTimeSeries
```

to

```
classdef (Sealed) arima_Custom < internal.econ.LagIndexableTimeSeries
```

Next, change line 406 from:

```
function OBJ = arima(varargin)
```

to

```
function OBJ = arima_Custom(varargin)
```

Now, change line 993 from:

```
if isa(OBJ.Variance, 'double') && (OBJ.Variance <= 0)
```

to

```
if isa(OBJ.Variance, 'double') && (sum(OBJ.Variance <= 0) > 0)
```

**v)** Open the `simulate.m` located in `@arima_Custom` for editing (we copied it there in step iii). It is probably best to open this file by navigating to it manually in the Current Folder window, to ensure the correct `simulate.m` is opened. In this file, alter line 310 from:

```
E(:,(maxPQ + 1:end)) = Z * sqrt(variance);
```

to

```
%Check that the input variance is of the right length (if it isn't scalar)
if isscalar(variance) == 0
    if size(variance, 2) ~= 1
        error('Deterministic variance must be a column vector');
    end
    if size(variance, 1) ~= numObs
        error('Deterministic variance vector is incorrect length relative to number of observations');
    end
else
    variance = variance(ones(numObs, 1));
end
%Scale innovations using deterministic variance
E(:,(maxPQ + 1:end)) =  sqrt(ones(numPaths, 1) * variance') .* Z;
```

And we're done!

You should now be able to simulate with deterministically time-varying variance using the `arima_Custom` class, for example (for an ARIMA(0,1,0)):

```
ARIMAModel = arima_Custom('D', 1, 'Variance', ScalarVariance, 'Constant', 0);
ARIMAModel.Variance = TimeVaryingVarianceVector;
[X, e, VarianceVector] = simulate(ARIMAModel, NumObs, 'numPaths', NumPaths);
```

Further, you should also still be able to use matlab's original `arima` class, since we didn't alter it.